# How can I compute another bit pattern with identical SHA-160 sum?

Tags: c++, sha, false-positive, botan

I want to test my application when it gets tricked by a false passed SHA-160 sum and thus would like to compute a change to the data being summed which results in the original SHA-160 sum again and thus would be missed. I am using the Botan library in C++ to compute the sum.

How can I compute a change to a bit stream that is around 1500 bits such that its SHA-160 is identical to the original?

Comment: IF this was easy, wouldn't it defeat the purpose?

Comment: Wikipedia says there's a collision attack by Marc Stevens which needs about 2^57.5 operations. Good luck :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't.

The long answer is: you can, but only with **vast** amounts of computation power.  The entire purpose of hash algorithms is to make it hard to find collisions.  If it were easy to find a collision, then there'd be little point in using the hash algorithm.

To solve your test problem, I suggest abstracting away the file-reading/hash-computing part of your application into a separate class, and then [*mocking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) it with a fake hash implementation in order to test the rest of the application.

Comment: +1. For testing, you can replace your SHA-160 function with an intentionally-broken hash function. (For example, you can specifically test for particular bit patterns and return the same hash for chosen patterns.)